# Changing background image of img element with sprites

Tags: html, css

Trying to change the background image of a button using CSS, JS and jQuery. HTML first:

```
<button id='btn_home'>
    <img class='home_green' src="images/menus.png">
</button>
```

Now the CSS:

```
.home_green {
    background:url(images/menus.png) 0 0;
}
.home_blue {
    background:url(images/menus.png) 0 -106px;
}
```

Here is the jQuery script. I don't think this is the problem because the console output is perfect:

```
$("#btn_home").find('img').hover(
    function () {
        console.log("mouse enter");
        $(this).removeClass('home_blue');
        $(this).addClass('home_green');
        console.log($(this).attr('class'));
    },
    function () {
        console.log("mouse leave");
        $(this).removeClass('home_green');
        $(this).addClass('home_blue');
        console.log($(this).attr('class'));
    }
);
```

I get no errors thrown, but no change to my background image, either. Pretty sure that I am defining something wrong in the relationship between my HTML and CSS, but I don't know what. Thanks for any help.

EDIT: Here is another attempt. When I try this, no image at all shows up. Everything else (CSS, jQuery) is the same:

```
<button id='btn_home' class='home_green'></button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by `CSS`

you can add styles to `button` itself instead of `img` just add a `width` and `height`

```
<button id='btn_home'></button>

 .btn_home {
   background:url(images/menus.png) 0 0;
 }
 .btn_home:hover {
   background:url(images/menus.png) 0 -106px;
 }
```

```css
div {
  width: 89px;
  height: 91px;
}
button {
  background: url(http://kaioa.com/b/0907/sprite_eyecatcher.png) no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
  background-position: -5px -4px;
  padding: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button:hover {
  background-position: -94px -4px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id='btn_home'></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It's not quite that simple. The image can start as either green or blue, so I need jQuery to identify what the starting image is so that it can be flipped. Still, I think your suggestion is good. I'm going to edit my OP to show an attempt similar to what you suggest.

Comment: you will need to add `width` and `height` for the `button` @usr55410

Comment: Those properties inherit from parent elements.

Comment: see my attached snippet @usr55410

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yvax8qje/1/) to accomplish what you want.

Correct, you can just set a background image to the `<button>` element, and remove the `<img>` inside.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: If you want JS to simply flip the color, you will have to have an "if" statement inside your jQuery hover functions to flip the class for you. If the class is currently "home_blue" remove it and add "home_green", and vice versa.